# Go back to HTML page from flex page

Tags: html, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

In my application I am having a HTML file which is calling a SWF file (flex page) when a button got clicked. I am performing some operations in the loaded flex page and while clicking submit in that flex page, I want to close that flex page and show the HTML page where the SWF file got loaded. How to achieve this with ActionScript.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific?

Comment: What does an HTML calling a SWF file mean?  Call how?  In what way?  Is the button that get clicked in your HTML page or in your Flex app?  Usually a Flex app (SWF) is embedded in an HTML page. Is the SWF you want to communicate with part of your HTML Page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only Actionscript wont solve your issue, you need to have some javascript knowledge to handle it.
You will embed your swf in a div in the html, initially dont display the DIV, once you click some button in the html page, you can display the DIV which holds the swf.

In the Actionscript, write a Externalinterface method to call a javascript function in the html, this javascript function will hide the same div.